# Sublime text. A kinda macro for creating a pair of .h and .cpp for class

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

So I'm tired of creating two new files for every class I make. AFAIK, macros don't record actions such as creating new files. Snippets also can't create new files. I want to press a kinda hotkey to create a new .h and .cpp file with a specified name. Maybe with a class template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AdvancedNewFile to create multiple files at the same time with the curly brace expansion. For example, inputting `test.{cpp,h}` will create `test.cpp` and `test.h`. You will need to set `posix_input` to true for the expansion to work. Templates with expansion do not work (right now anyways), but that may change in the future. There may be other plugins with much more specific functionality out there, but I do not know of them.